# Meaning: "a race of one"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

This phrase is found in "*Stranger From a Strange Land*"  (*Robert Heinlein*).

> ONCE UPON A TIME when the world was young there was a Martian named Smith.
> Valentine Michael Smith was as real as taxes but he was a **race of one**.

It is found in a different context [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eLfaaP6ZsZYC&pg=PA19&dq=%22a+race+of+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi71a_m4uLtAhXDAmMBHR6dB6gQ6AEwCHoECC0QAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20race%20of%20one%22&f=false).

> We are all welcome in Your fold.
> We are all a flock of humble lambs
> Every women, kid, and man.
> Dear God, please bless your children all,
> A **race of one**, both big and small.

The following dictionaries remain mute: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one), [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/one_1), [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/one).

What is the meaning of "**race of one**", or more generaly of "**of one**"?

Comment: It works now...maybe because you refreshed it. Dunno. I'll check back in an hour.

Comment: Those are 2 different usages, meaning polar opposites. Valentine was the unique member of his own race. The Sunday school prayer you cited means all races are one.

Comment: @Cascabel A meaning subject to context will be the only way out then; however, if the first is clear enough, the second is confusing: is it a denial of the fact of race? Why use the term "race" at all then?

Comment: The book is in poorly written and should not be used as an example of English. *A race of one, both big and small.* does not sound at all idiomatic and the meaning is only available from the context and Galatians 3:28 . I also note that the book starts off with *Dear God, I pray/ You’ll keep me strong/ And not do things/ I know are wrong.*, which basically asks God not to do things that are wrong...

Comment: @Greybeard A very [reasonable thing to ask from him](https://www.angelfire.com/hi/littleprince/framechapter10.html), all things considered.

Comment: @Greybeard: For a moment there I thought your "book is poorly written" was talking about *Stranger From a Strange Land*! But yeah - that Xtian tract really is drivel. Just before the cited passage it's got a prayer where the first sentence is *Dear God I pray you'll keep me strong and not do things I know are wrong.* Bad enough that it's so trite, but it's not even "syntactically valid"!

Comment: @Greybeard - I think all of Heinlein's books were 'poorly written' in a fundamental sense, and I specially detest him for unleashing the 'word' _grok_ on the world.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey What do you reproach this new term with? It wouldn't add any connotations to "understand"?

Comment: I still shudder to recall a stoned earnest hippy trying to explain this marvellous new word he had found to a bunch of equally stoned people. It was around that time that I began to  think that maybe there were flaws in the notion that 'everything is cool, man'. It was 1970. I was 18.

Comment: @LPH yes, that, and I hate Heinlein the fascist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an idiom.  It's a phrase meaning that the race he belonged to -- Martian -- consisted of one human -- himself.

It's similar to "party of one" at a restaurant.

Comment: I did think about that, it did sound a likely possibility, but yet I find this phrase in another context (indicated in my question) where that is not a sensible solution; what do you think about this new context?

Comment: The thing is, even in a science fiction or fantasy context, it's very rare to find a race consisting of one individual.  It's more other groups that can be "group of one" and hence have the phrase appear.